# Typecasting integer to pointer to integer in c

Tags: c, pthreads

I saw somewhere in a pthreads program something like this...

```
#include<pthread.h>
#include<stdio.h>

void *fxn(void * t)
{
//some code
}

int main()
{
//some code
pthread_create(&thread,NULL,fxn,(int *)5);
//some code
}
```

Here, what is (int *)5 doing?
and why is it not generating a warning/error?
Also, how is it different from pthread_create(&thread,NULL,fxn,&x); where x=5 is of type int ?

Edit:

This works fine:

```
#include<pthread.h>
#include<stdio.h>

void * fxn(void *t)
{
    pthread_exit(t);
}
int main()
{
    pthread_t th;
    void *ret;
    int i=5;
    pthread_create(&th,NULL,fxn,&i);
    pthread_join(th,&ret);
    printf("%d\n",*(int *)ret);
}
```

but,

```
#include<pthread.h>
#include<stdio.h>

void * fxn(void *t)
{
    pthread_exit(t);
}
int main()
{
    pthread_t th;
    void *ret;
    int i=5;
    pthread_create(&th,NULL,fxn,(int *)5);
    pthread_join(th,&ret);
    printf("%d\n",*(int *)ret);
}
```

gives segmentation fault,core dumped...Why?

Comment: Suppose you want to pass value 5 to the thread. In this case `(int *)5` is used. In the thread function: `int n = (int)t;` gives 5. In the case `&x` where `x=5` you need to ensure that `x` variable does not change and doesn't go out of scope.

Comment: The reason for segmentation fault in second case is that `pthread_exit()` dereferences `t` (within its body), which is invalid pointer (as described in answers).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically, `(int *)5` interprets `5` as an address.  The result is typically a pointer to the address `0x0005` in your address space.

In this case, that's almost certainly not the real intention.  (Such an address is almost always invalid if you're not doing low-level system stuff, at which point you probably don't have `pthread_create` available anyway.)

Here, since `pthread_create` takes a `void *` as some "extra data" to pass to the thread's startup function (in this case `fxn`), whatever data you want to pass via that argument must be converted to a pointer.

The code in `fxn` will typically include an expression like `(int)t` to convert the pointer back into an integer.  That's basically the only useful thing that can be done with it -- you're the only one that knows your pointer isn't *really* a pointer, and if anything (like, say, the last line of your `main` function...) ever tries to actually use it as a pointer, it's quite likely to trigger a segfault.

Comment: By the way, i'm not sure, but conversion to `int *` might technically be allowed to tweak the value to satisfy alignment constraints.  In any case, you're probably better off converting directly to `void *` rather than `int *`, if you have no intention of actually dereferencing the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

You don't get an error because by casting you tell the compiler that you know what you are doing.

The cast `(int*)5` converts 5 to an int pointer pointing to some( very likely )invalid address. To get that value in the thread you have to cast void pointer back to an integer `(int)t`. Do not do this.

Passing `&x`, gets you a pointer to a variable `x`, which you can use in the thread function. Similar to this:

```
int x = 123 ;
int* px = &x ;
pthread_create(&thread,NULL,fxn,px);
```

And in the thread:

```
int* pt = t ;
printf( "%d" , *pt ) ;
```

Comment: The problem with passing a real pointer to a local variable is unless you know for sure that the current function will continue running for a good long while, your pointer may well be invalid by the time `fxn` starts.  If you really really want to pass a valid pointer, get it via `malloc` and have `fxn` free it.

Comment: @cHao You just made that up, there is not such problem in this case. Look at OP's example.

Comment: I'm looking at it -- and it's demonstrating the exact problem i'm bringing up.  Since the function can return soon after the thread is created, semantically your `x` may no longer exist and the pointer will be invalid.

Comment: Ahh...i didn't, actually.  I was looking at a previous revision -- didn't see it had changed.

Answer (score -1):

`(int*)5` means casting 5 to a pointer to an int.

This makes possible to pass a pointer which points to 5 in memory to the function `pthread_create`.

For example:

```
(int) 5; //cast to int
(int *) 5; //cast to pointer to int
```

Comment: No, it's not at all the same as passing the address of a variable whose value is `5`.